# Throw exception or return any result?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm programming WPF application using MVVM pattern and have dilemma. In ViewModel I have instance of BusinessLogic. Here is function:

```
public async Task StartService(string password = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            _serviceController.Start(new[] {password});
            await _serviceController.WaitForStatusAsync(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        }
        else if (TokenAccessFileExists())
        {
            _serviceController.Start();
            await _serviceController.WaitForStatusAsync(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("TADA");

    }
```

This function is called from VM. But I'm not sure what to do, if the conditions are not true. I should throw expcetion and catch it in VM or return custom result?

Many thanks for answer

**EDIT:**
To be more clear:
I'm asking, which approach is more convenient: throw exception from service layer and handle it in VM, or return some type of result to VM.

Comment: Either works, providing the calling code handles it correctly. But I'd throw an exception, since the return type isn't really consistent with reporting an error.

Comment: A login failure in an MVVM application should update a status view model of some sort to let the user know the problem.  Normally you handle that with a custom result rather than exceptions.

Comment: But to handle the error in VM correctly, I should throw different exceptions (e.g: NoPasswordException, NoTokenException). Am I right?

Comment: @JuP You could do that, but it would be simpler to have a single `ValidationFailureException` and state the reason in the `Message` property. Or just `throw Exception("Invalid Password")`, `throw Exception("No token")`, etc. Don't write a custom exception class unless you'll need to handle that case differently. Here, if validation failed, it failed; the reason will be in `ex.Message`. That's all you need to know, most likely.

Comment: Many thanks Ed. I like your approach. But I cannot mark your comment as an answer. Could you write answer?

Comment: @JuP "Unclear what you're asking". It literally could not have been more clear. I keep a pikestaff in my office for purposes of comparison, and it is *substantially less plain* than the meaning of this question.

Comment: I understand your answer/advice. But I cannot accept/mark your comment as an answer. There's no such functionality.

Comment: @JuP Right, and since your question was closed for the preposterous reasons I mention above, I can't post an answer. Not your fault. No big deal, either.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are correct.

You could simply throw an exception, and handle it in the caller.

Or you could create a structure like this to describe the success/failure of the operation:

```
class StartServiceResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Then your code becomes

```
public async Task<StartServiceResult> StartService(string password = null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        _serviceController.Start(new[] {password});
        await _serviceController.WaitForStatusAsync(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        return new StartServiceResult { Success = true, Message = "Started from password" };
    }
    else if (TokenAccessFileExists())
    {
        _serviceController.Start();
        await _serviceController.WaitForStatusAsync(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        return new StartServiceResult { Success = true, Message = "Started from token" };
    }
    return new StartServiceResult { Success = false, Message = "Failed to start: no password nor token." };
}
```

You could also use an enum instead of a string message:

```
enum StartServiceResultType
{
    SuccessFromPassword,
    SuccessFromToken,
    Failure
}
```

Comment: This is one option. But I was thinking, if this approach is not C++ oldschool.